# Modificar formato fecha (dd/mm/yyyy) que devuelve un input type date al mostrarlo en un label con javascript

Tags: javascript

Buenas tardes, tengo la siguiente consulta:
Tengo un script que copia el valor que elijo en un input type date y lo muestra en un label (Lo muestra ahi por que todo los label ademas de este estan adentro de un div que copio con clipboard.min.js desde un boton, pero en fin)

Lo que necesito es mostrar la fecha en formato dd/mm/yyyy en el label ya que actualmente me la muestra yyyy/mm/dd ya que el script trae el valor que elijo en el input date:
¿Me dan una mano? Muchas gracias.

Script e input:

```
<script>
    function desde(obj) {
      document.getElementById("desde").textContent = obj.value
    }
    </script>

  <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">DESDE:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  <input type="date" id="" name="Desde" class="form-control" required 
  onchange="desde(this)" onpaste="return false">
  </div>
```

Y lo muestro en el label:

```
 <p>Desde: <label id="desde"></label></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gracias Vera. Probe todas las variables pero solo me funcionaba una que usa JSON y en un archivo aparte, si la usaba en el que lo necesito me tiraba un NO DATE: Termine decidiendo cambiar el input date y usar uno text con una funcion que evita que escriban mal la fecha, le saco la posibilidad de seleccionar la fecha pero le dejo la posibilidad de validarles que la escriban bien si o si.
Muchas gracias.

```
<input name="fecha" type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" onKeyUp = 
"this.value=formateafecha(this.value);"> 
<SCRIPT>
function IsNumeric(valor) 
{ 
var log=valor.length; var sw="S"; 
for (x=0; x<log; x++) 
{ v1=valor.substr(x,1); 
v2 = parseInt(v1); 
//Compruebo si es un valor numérico 
if (isNaN(v2)) { sw= "N";} 
} 
if (sw=="S") {return true;} else {return false; } 
} 
var primerslap=false; 
var segundoslap=false; 
function formateafecha(fecha) 
{ 
var long = fecha.length; 
var dia; 
var mes; 
var ano; 
if ((long>=2) && (primerslap==false)) { dia=fecha.substr(0,2);  
if ((IsNumeric(dia)==true) && (dia<=31) && (dia!="00")) { 
fecha=fecha.substr(0,2)+"/"+fecha.substr(3,7); primerslap=true; } 
else { fecha=""; primerslap=false;} 
} 
else 
{ dia=fecha.substr(0,1); 
if (IsNumeric(dia)==false) 
{fecha="";} 
if ((long<=2) && (primerslap=true)) {fecha=fecha.substr(0,1); 
primerslap=false; } 
 } 
 if ((long>=5) && (segundoslap==false)) 
 { mes=fecha.substr(3,2); 
 if ((IsNumeric(mes)==true) &&(mes<=12) && (mes!="00")) { 
 fecha=fecha.substr(0,5)+"/"+fecha.substr(6,4); segundoslap=true; } 
 else { fecha=fecha.substr(0,3);; segundoslap=false;} 
 } 
 else { if ((long<=5) && (segundoslap=true)) { fecha=fecha.substr(0,4); 
 segundoslap=false; } } 
 if (long>=7) 
 { ano=fecha.substr(6,4);   
 if (IsNumeric(ano)==false) { fecha=fecha.substr(0,6); } 
 else { if (long==10){ if ((ano==0) || (ano<1900) || (ano>2100)) { 
 fecha=fecha.substr(0,6); } } } 
 } 
 if (long>=10) 
 { 
 fecha=fecha.substr(0,10); 
 dia=fecha.substr(0,2); 
 mes=fecha.substr(3,2); 
 ano=fecha.substr(6,4); 
 // Año no viciesto y es febrero y el dia es mayor a 28 
 if ( (ano%4 != 0) && (mes ==02) && (dia > 28) ) { 
 fecha=fecha.substr(0,2)+"/"; } 
 } 
 return (fecha);  
 }
 </SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 0):

A mi se me ocurre que, si en el script que "pone" la fecha en el input buscas el archivo o archivos js que conforman el script, en algún punto, seguro seguro, que puedes modificar el formato de la fecha que acaba mostrando en el input.

Si no, pues se me ocurre quizá en el evento "onChange()" disparar una función parecida a esta:

```
function formatDate(date) {
  var monthNames = [
    "January", "February", "March",
    "April", "May", "June", "July",
    "August", "September", "October",
    "November", "December"
  ];

  var day = date.getDate();
  var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
  var year = date.getFullYear();

  return day + ' ' + monthNames[monthIndex] + ' ' + year;
}
```

Comment: Pasa que es un input de html, solo tiene el type date, ya viene por default. Luego ese valor lo mando al label segun el id. Por eso no se si me conviene seguir asi o meter un datapicker de javascript en vez del input.

Comment: En tal caso... lee aquí : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es el date formateado y que se muestre en el input, te recomiendo usar [DatePicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) de la librería [JQuery](https://www.google.com.do/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjOn7q1ne_XAhUB4iYKHaNhCB8QFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fjquery.com%2F&usg=AOvVaw1yb1TgbSxtZNKnsTynd_HN), es bien sencillo.

Esto es debido a que no se puede formatear el `<input type="date">`